# How to use mysql_field_name or mysqli_fetch_field to display Column Name And Value Side By Side

Tags: php

I have to write an application that displays a multicolumn value table in two columns(I posted a question concerning that earlier,but i have done some research which has sharpened my perspective). Each individual has a single entry in the table.The task is to display the values in these columns in a two column table.

The columns are for subjects that the individual has registered for.
ie.

```
       MATH111,MATH112,ENG111,ENG112
```

Etc.These columns are dynamic in nature,because they are based on column headings in an excel sheet which are being loaded into a database. In light of this, i can not "hardcode" the name of the table in my html

```
          <th>MATH111</th><th>MATH112</th>........
```

I need to grab the column names at run time,display the name of the column "**AND**"the value contained in it. The only fixed value in the table is the reg_no of the student.
All other values are arbitrary(including the number of columns in the table).

The basic structure of the table is:

```
       id int auto_increment primary key,
       reg_no varchar(25),
       arbitrary col1 int,
       arbitrary col2 int,
       arbitrary col3 int,
       arbitrary col4 int,
       arbitrary  colx....
```

In line with the above if i query arbitrary col1 i will get the score obtained in the course that arbitrary col1 represents.

I need to display them in a web-page in the follwing format:

```
      echo '<table><tr><th>Course</th><th>Score</th></tr>';
```

My query to get the data from the table is

```
         $sql="select * from '.$table_name.' where reg_no='.$reg_no.';
    ...................................(blah...)
```

The good part is that i know the number of columns in the table.(As this figure is saved during table creation). A little research i did yielded the finding that i could use the 'mysql_field_name' function. Or the mysqli_fetch_field function.

The mysql_field_name will be used in this way(which in my opinion is easier):

```
        $result=mysql_query($sql, $link); 
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

From here on...i will need some tips:

I want to display "**BOTH**" The field name and the value of the field. So this is how i intend to do it.Please correct me if i am wrong.

$numberofcolumnsintable=$numberofcolumnsintable++;

```
 while(int i=1;i<=$numberofcolumnsintable;$i++)
        (I am starting from the index 1(second column because i do not want to display the reg_no or its data)
     {   echo"<tr><td>".mysql_field_name($result,$i)."</td>"<td>".$result[$i]."</td></tr>";
      }
echo "</table>";
```

Am I doing it right. I am more comfortable with mysqli functions...but it uses the mysqli_fetch_field function which returns an object with properties of the column..which i have not yet figured out how to access. Any help on that will also be grateful. So back to my main question. Is the code i showed above sufficient to display the column name and its value side by side?.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [mysql(i)_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) instead of [mysql(i)_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array). That way you'll get an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with both the column name and the value. A simple foreach will then do it:

```
$rows = mysqli_query('select * from tbl');
foreach($rows as $column => $value) {
    echo $column . ": " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

`$rows` may look something like this:

```
array(
    array('reg_no' => '321', 'col1' => 'foo'),
    array('reg_no' => '654', 'col1' => 'knox')
);
```